# sftp user can't see files, what is the right permission

Tags: permissions, files

I installed a Magento on `/var/www/html` and set all files in it owned by `www-data` and group `www-data`.

Added a user to be a member of `www-data` and use that user on sftp.

Directory is set with permission for the owner to be `rwx` and group is `rw`.

When I use filezilla and access `/var/www/html`, it is empty, files are somehow hidden.

What's causing this or what am I missing?

Does htaccess have something to do with it? I checked the htaccess nothing in it that should affect the files being hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you have described, i.e.

> directories is set with permission of the owner to be `rwx` and group is `rw`

if this has been applied to the `/var/www/html` directory and everything underneath it, your sftp user can't `cd` into any of the directories because they belong to the `www-data` group which only has `rw` permissions.
Try giving the `www-data` group `rwx` permissions.

```
sudo chmod -vR 775 /var/www/html
```

Comment: what is the v for?

Comment: verbose . it displays the result of the command

Comment: is it necessary to add 5 permission for other groups?

Comment: did the command `sudo chmod -vR 775 /var/www/html` work for you? `755` is the default. `5` on a directory simply means `other`'s can enter the dir and `ls`the files but not create, delete or rename files

Comment: yes the 7 rwx worked well. what is s really? tried rws on group my virtual ubuntu and that worked fine. dont know really what is "s" does.

Comment: its the setgid bit. any direcotry that has setgid set will cause that dirs group to apply to newly created children directories AND also set the setgid bit on those newborn children too. this means children of those children get the original group and setgid , and also the chuldren of those children.... etc .